# How to check the first two values of a string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I would like to check the input value of a telephone number (to check if it starts with 06 or 07) and accordingly make changes in a query.

How to go about this?

Will the following work:

```
char first = strNewTel.Trim()[0];
char sec = strNewTel.Trim()[1];
```

...and then check the two chars if they match.

Or is there an better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the format  of the phone number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strNewTel)
    && (strNewTel.StartsWith("06")
        || strNewTel.StartsWith("07")) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple as that:

```
if (strNewTel.Trim().StartsWith("06") || strNewTel.Trim().StartsWith("07"))
{
    // DoSomething
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String phone = "067-123-4567";
if (phone.StartsWith("06")) { 
    //add logic here
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
  strNewTel.StartsWith("06")||strNewTel.StartsWith("07")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not `StartsWith` that should do the job

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right and you mean "check if number starts from 06 or 07" then use

```
 strNewTel.Trim().StartsWith("06")
```